# Criteria When Evaluating Middleware

Tags: middleware

What are some suitable criteria for evaluating a list of Companies complimentary middleware? I am doing a trade study on several Company's middleware implementations and so far I have came up with the following criteria:

1. Cost
2. Ease of Development/Ramp Up Time
3. Licensing
4. Support
5. Quality of Tools

Comment: Sorry to be thick-headed, but can you give some examples of tools you are evaluating.  I read developer tools and then middleware and my head starts to buzz because to me they are not so related.

Comment: @Jeff: I'm sorry fixed the title. DDS is the middleware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a solid start. I would add:

- How wide spread is the usage, and how easy is it to hire people with experience using the technology.

If you are planing on using the technology for a long time, choosing one where its possible to hire people who already know it can be a big saving for you.